# Definition of Clifford super-connections

Tags: clifford-algebras, dirac-operator

I have some questions concerning the definition of Clifford super-connections in [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628):

> **Definition 3.39.** If $A$ is a super-connection on a Clifford module $E\to M$, we say that $A$ is a
> Clifford super-connection if
> \begin{equation}\tag{3.12}
> \forall a \in \Gamma(M,C(M)):[A, c(a)] = c(\nabla a).
> \end{equation}
> In this case $(3.12)$ holds for all $a \in \Omega(M, C(M))$.

1. Am I right that the LHS of $(3.12)$ is not a super-commutator, but a commutator? Otherwise I think that the definition is not consistent with the definition of Clifford connections: If $a$ is a vector field, then $c(a)$ is odd and hence the super-commutator $[A,c(a)]$ is an anti-commutator.
2. Am I right that it is enough to require that $(3.12)$ holds for all vector fields? Because if $a_1$ and $a_2$ both satisfy $(3.12)$, then $a_1+a_2$ and $a_1 a_2$ do too since $\nabla(a_1a_2)=(\nabla a_1)a_2+a_1(\nabla a_2)$.
3. Regarding the comment below $(3.12)$: Am I right that
   \begin{equation}
   \forall a \in \Omega^k(M,C(M)):A\circ c(a)-(-1)^{k}c(a)\circ A = c(\nabla a)
   \end{equation}
   (I added the proof below)? Again the LHS is not the super-commutator of the endomorphisms $A$ and $c(a)$ on the super-vector space $\Omega(M,E)$, this is why I would appreciate a confirmation. Note that this means that $\{A,c(\nabla a)\}=c(\nabla^2 a)$ for a vector field $a$, which is what we need in the proof of proposition 3.43.

---

Suppose that $\omega\in\Omega^k(M)$, $a\in\Gamma(M,TM)$ and $\phi\in\Gamma(M,E)$. Then
\begin{align}
&A(c(\omega\otimes a)\phi)-(-1)^kc(\omega\otimes a)A(\phi)=A(\omega\otimes c(a)\phi)-(-1)^k\omega\wedge c(a)A(\phi)=\\
&=(-1)^k\omega\wedge A(c(a)\phi)+\mathrm{d}\omega\otimes c(a)\phi-(-1)^k\omega\wedge c(a)A(\phi)\\
&=(-1)^k\omega\wedge(Ac(a)\phi-c(a)A\phi)+\mathrm{d}\omega\otimes c(a)\phi\\
&=(-1)^k\omega\wedge c(\nabla a)\phi+\mathrm{d}\omega\otimes c(a)\phi\\
&=c((-1)^k\omega\wedge\nabla a+\mathrm d\omega\otimes a)\phi=c(\nabla(\omega\otimes a))\phi
\end{align}

Comment: In fact, there is an ordinary Clifford connection and superconnection, so In here supercommutator seems right. For 3, does it still hold when you use the action appearing below Proposition 3.35?

Comment: @ChoMedit "so in here super-commutator seems right" - Sorry, I don't understand your reasoning. I think that each Clifford connection is supposed to be a Clifford super-connection, i.e. the latter is a generalization.

Comment: @ChoMedit In fact I think that this (the fact that each Clifford connection is a Clifford super-connection) plays a fundamental role in the proof of the index theorem: First we prove it for a Clifford connection and then we use that if it holds for one Clifford super-connection/Dirac operator, then it holds for all Clifford super-connections.

Comment: @ChoMedit Furthermore it is important that we can identify Dirac operators and Clifford super-connections and the proof uses the fact that Clifford super-connections form an affine space with translation space $\Omega(M,\mathrm{End}_{C(M)}(E))$. But this requires a commutator in the definition of Clifford super-connections, since we agree that $\mathrm{End}_{C(M)}(E)$ commutes with the Clifford action.

Comment: I think there are two possibilities : i) In here, $\mathrm{End}_{C(M)}(E)$ is a collection of supercommuting endomorphisms. ii) $\mathrm{End}_{C(M)}(E)$ is a collection of commuting endomorphisms and your correction is right. Since we don't know the consistent definition of $\mathrm{End}_{C(M)}(E)$.. everything seems messy..

Comment: @ChoMedit Well, we agree on the meaning of $\mathrm{End}_{C(M)}(E)$ when we write $$\mathrm{End}(E)\cong C(M)\otimes\mathrm{End}_{C(M)}(E),$$right? But this isomorphism appears in the proof that the function mapping each super-connection to a Dirac operator is invertible, so  I think that it must be (ii).

Comment: @ChoMedit In fact I conjecture that we could first consider pre-Clifford bundles (Clifford bundles without a grading) and establish that we have a one to one correspondance between Clifford super-connections and Dirac operators (where super-connections and Dirac operators and not required to be odd). Then we see that if we are given a grading such that Clifford multiplication is even, then a Dirac operator is odd if and only if the associated connection is odd as well.